# How to get the anchor and paragraph in the same line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Im trying to create a project with LeafletJs and this includes making a panel which displays all the store locations like this:
[image]

but, i want the name of the store, 'pizza outlet x' to come on a separate line, before the address.
this is the code

```
const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
const attribution =
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Coded by coder\'s gyan with ❤️';
const tileLayer = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, { attribution });
tileLayer.addTo(myMap);

function makeList() {
    const ul = document.querySelector('.list');
    storeList.forEach((shop) => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        const para = document.createElement('para');

        div.classList.add('shop-item');
        anchor.innerText = shop.properties.name;
        anchor.href = '#';
        para.innerText = shop.properties.address;

        div.appendChild(anchor);
        div.appendChild(para);
        li.appendChild(div);
        ul.appendChild(li);

    });


}

makeList();
```

How do i do this?

Comment: You should achieve the same with css. Add `display: block` to the class of  `pizza outlet x`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add a br tag ? Using your method:

const br = document.createElement('br');

div.appendChild(br); //place this after anchor

Comment: Ohh okay
thank you so much!
Im actually new to JS and im just going through someone else's code

Comment: No worries...can you do me a favour and mark the answer as correct.